# partial load of matlab (.mat) files -v7 in python

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, hdf5, mat-file

I have a large set of `matlab` files data files which I need to access in `Python`.
The files were saved using `save` with `-v6` or `-v7` option, but not the `-v7.3`.

I have to read only one single numerical value from each file, the files are many (100k+) and relatively large (1MB+).
Therefore, I spend 99% of time idling in I/O operations which are useless.

I am looking for something like partial load, which is feasible for -v7.3 files using HDF5 library.

So far, I have bee using the `scipy.io.loadmat` API.

Documentation says:

```
v4 (Level 1.0), v6 and v7 to 7.2 matfiles are supported.
You will need an HDF5 python library to read matlab 7.3 format mat files. 
Because scipy does not supply one, we do not implement the HDF5 / 7.3 interface here.
```

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.loadmat.html

But it looks like it does not allow partial load.

Does anyone have experience with implementing such a feature, or does anyone know how to parse these .mat files at a lower level?

I guess a `fseek`-like approach could be possible when the structure is known

Comment: Do you want to reada single variable?

Comment: yes, this would already save quite some time. ideally, I would need to read the first value of one of the arrays stored

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `variable_names` parameter if you want to read a single variable:

```
d = loadmat(filename, variable_names=['variable_name'])
```

then access it as follows:

```
d['variable_name']
```

**UPDATE:** if you need just a first element of an array/matrix you can do this:

```
val = loadmat(filename, variable_names=['var_name']).get('var_name')[0, 0]
```

NOTE: it will still read the whole variable into memory, but it will be deleted after first element is assigned to `val`.

Comment: any ways to load part of a variable?